# Cloudera REST Api to fetch Task resource

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager, bigdata

Getting difficulties to find the correct API and URL to fetch the Task resource against a particular application from Cloudera-Admin (CDH5).
I have already checked it's API doc for the same, but unable to find the correct one. Task details was available for CDH4 as below.

https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hadoop/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/MapredAppMasterRest.html#Task_API 
http:///proxy/application_1326232085508_0004/ws/v1/mapreduce/jobs/job_1326232085508_4_4/task

I am looking for the same with CDH5.

May I have any help on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the one you are searching for: https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WebServicesIntro.html

> http://host.domain.com:8088/proxy/{appid}/ws/v1/mapreduce/jobs/{jobid}/tasks
>
> http://host.domain.com:8088/proxy/{appid}/ws/v1/mapreduce/jobs/{jobid}/tasks/{taskid}/attempts

curl command is used in the examples given. I have removed the appid, jobid and taskid from the example and posted here.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I was looking for this. But apart from getting JSON response from REST URL, is there any other way to use API in code to get the "Task Details" of a job. I have already used "com.cloudera.api" package to query and fetch job details from Cloudera manger, but don't know how to get the task details of a job.

Comment: @abhijitnag : I think you are talking about RESTful-java-client. You can try out Jersey library https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html

Comment: No Marc, I am looking for REST service exposed from Cloudera, not the client.  As I have already used "http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v10/" for the same, but this API doesn't provide any information on Task detail for job.

Comment: @abhijitnag : You mentioned in your first comment that you want to "fetch job details from Cloudera manager".  This means you want to be a consumer and so I mentioned of RESTful client. Is my understanding correct?